# scrape data from website using date range using vba

Tags: vba, excel

i have a question. i am pulling the data from the website using date range of last 15days. when i enter from and to dates i get data displayed for 6 colums and i need to copy it into excel sheet data. below is my code which i tried but not able to execute it. please help.

```
Sub scrapedata()
  Dim eRow As Long
  Dim ele As Object
  Dim objIE
  Set sht = Sheets("Data")
  
    RowCount = 1
    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Product(s)"
    sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Manufacturer"
    sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "NOC with conditions"
    sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Notice of Compliance date"
    sht.Range("E" & RowCount) = "Medicinal ingredient(s)"
    sht.Range("F" & RowCount) = "DIN(s)"
  
  eRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

mynocFromDate = InputBox("enter from date eg.2016-10-01")
mynocToDate = InputBox("enter to date eg.2016-10-05")
  With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://health-products.canada.ca/noc-ac/index-eng.jsp"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
      DoEvents
    Loop

setcol -sm - 6 = .document.getElementsByname("q")
col-sm-6.Item(o).Value = nocFromDate

setcol -sm - 6 = .document.getElementsByname("nocToDate")
col -sm - 6.Item(o).Value = nocToDate

.document.getElementById("mrgn-tp-md").Click

For Each ele In .document.all
      Select Case ele.classname
        Case "table-responsive"
          RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Case "Product"
         sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
        Case "Manufacturer"
          sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
        Case "NOC with conditions"
          sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
        Case "Notice of Compliance date"
          sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
        Case "Medicinal ingredient(s)"
          sht.Range("E" & RowCount) = ele.innerText
        Case "DIN(s)"
          sht.Range("F" & RowCount) = ele.innerTex
      End Select
    Next
  End With
  Set objIE = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question you literally just posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894449/excel-vba-code-to-scrap-data-from-website-using-date-range

Comment: Yeah, it was posted twice because of my internet problem - http://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory

Comment: Then you should close the oldest one to avoid duplicates ;)

Comment: Yeah, I m trying.very soon you will be seeing one only. Can you help me on my question?